# How to call function on swipe?

Tags: android

I have implement on click button to do some thing and go to next activity. How to call this ( button.performClick() ) on swipe ? What listener to implement and catch ? Just on swipe to call button.performClick().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use  onGestureListner and GestureDetector to catch onFling occasion and write necessary code there

http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-gestures.html

Refer to above page for more details